# How to create a tex file in which reflections of the top will be in the bottom of the same page?

Tags: reflection, shipout

I want to prepare a **.tex** document using *TeXStudio* satisfying the following:

- Take an A4 size paper.
- What ever is written in the top half of the page.
- Same writing will be reflected on the bottom half of the page.
- Whether I read from top or bottom it is the same, i.e., same margin (top,bottom), indent etc.
- Like the following example below.

[image: I want this]

Comment: Use a \savebox, minipage and \rotatebox (from the graphicx package).  Stick a \vfill in between the top and bottom \usebox.  If you want text to flow across pages, that will be much more difficult.

Comment: Or you can do it in two steps.  Create a half page document (literally) then use pdfpages or \includegrahics to copy these pages into a new document.

Comment: Your first comment is not clear to me, Please give a minimal example.

Comment: Second one is okay. But every time I write any thing I have to take the half page and include it as a figure file, which is not a good idea. Is there any other way to do this?                     In my example even though I have presented boxed material, but my intention was for all (documents as well as figures).                                 For Example In case of Exam class I want my questions reflected as above in a page, so that I can save paper.

Comment: I think @JohnKormylo's 2nd solution is the best easy one. you need 2 files .tex let say source.tex and final.tex you don't need to change any thing in final.tex you just use it to produce your final output.

Comment: @touhami But every time I have to run the program twice.  First-generate the first pdf page and then include it as two figure files**************************\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Pages1.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7,angle=180]{Pages1.pdf}
\end{document}
*************************************************

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `atbegshi` captures the output box before it is shipped out. This can be used to place a rotated copy of the page on the output page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=15mm]{geometry}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-.5\paperheight}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutInit
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(\paperwidth, -.5\paperheight){%
      \rotatebox{180}{%
        \smash{\hbox to 0pt{\kern1in\copy\AtBeginShipoutBox\hss}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

First two pages:

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]

Comment: This is the code I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

THis the `source.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape]{geometry}


\usepackage{blindtext}% just for dummy example
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
and this is your `final.tex` produce the output you dont need to change it every time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,scale=1]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcounter{mtpage}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\loop
\stepcounter{mtpage}
\includegraphics[scale=.99,page=\value{mtpage}]{doc1.pdf}
\vfill\includegraphics[scale=.99,angle=180,page=\value{mtpage}]{doc1.pdf}
\newpage
\ifnum\value{mtpage}<\pdflastximagepages
\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any alternative to this method. Is it possible to get the required result from your **Source.tex** file, with out using any other *.tex* file (**final.tex**).

Comment: @LitunJohn see Heiko Oberdiek's answer.